# Resistor Divider Circuit with Voltage Bias

Tags: voltage, resistors

Could someone please help me to calculate the output voltage across the voltmeter of a resistor divider network as shown in below schematic whose input can vary from -20V to +20V, R1 = 43K, R2 = 5.1K and Bias Voltage on R2 is 2.5V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuNv6J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Handy formula, and it works a treat!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Forget about VM1, If we simplified the circuit and connect two Voltage source of 20 V and 2.5 V, by connecting their `GND`, over all voltage should be **20V - 2.5V = 17.5 V**, now two resistor in series, so over all current trough circuit is,
**I = V / R**. where **R = 43 + 5.1 = 48.1 kOhm**, and **V = 17.5 V** so **I = 17.5 V / 48.1 kOhm = 0.363825364 mA**,
Now as you can see, voltage drop across R2 is,

Voltage drop across **V_R2 = R2 x I = 1.855509356 V** and finally Volt Meter will read value **Vm1 = V_R2 + V1 = 2.5 + 1.855509356 = 4.355509356 V**

Is that clear?

Comment: He's looking for the general formula to cover V2 from -20 V to +20 V. You have only provided a specific answer at one input voltage. "k" for kilo. "K" is for kelvin. 9 decimal places on your calculations is _probably_ a bit silly given practical resistor tolerances.

Comment: oh yes... i updated for that